# RelativeLayout limits after adding ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am adding a ScrollView as parent of a RelativeLayout, but when I do so my RelativeLayout limits to a little area and I can't change it.
When I change the padding I can fix the things in their place, but it is not a good way.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relatOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">


            <!--textArea Title-->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textArea"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
                android:hint="Write your message here!"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColorHint="#8e8e8e" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textArea"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Text:"
                android:textColor="@color/textAreaTitle"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/btnColor"
                android:onClick="btnSetter"
                android:text="Set on Channel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ScrollView is designed to be the root element. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make ScrollView as parent Root element not as Child in your case Change your Layout like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">


            <!--textArea Title-->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                android:hint="Write your message here!"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColorHint="#8e8e8e" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textArea"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Text:"

                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:onClick="btnSetter"
                android:text="Set on Channel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Change Your Linear Layout gravity and margin according to your need

Comment: I did what you said  and my RelativeLayout is the same . my virtual phone frame disappeared too.

Comment: @Elijah show your screen shot let me see exact problem with screen shot

Comment: @Elijah so you have 1 edit text 1 text view and 1 button

Comment: @Elijah Check Updated Answer

Comment: it worked with android:fillViewport="true" .I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3S9y.png)

I have this problem now after making ScrollView to root parent.

Comment: @androidXP here is my screenshot